# How can I add assembly binding logs to my MSBuild output?

Tags: .net, ssis, msbuild, teamcity, .net-assembly

I have an SSIS project that builds successfully locally, but does not build when it is run on our build server (TeamCity). I get errors along the lines of

> SSISBuild.proj(11, 5): Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I have the relevant file checked into source control.  Clearly, I'm having some kind of error loading/finding that file.  Is there any way, through MSBuild or the underlying TeamCity agent, to produce more detailed logs as to the Assembly Binding/Discovery process that was executed, in order to enable me to troubleshoot this issue with a little more clarity?

Answer (score 0):

MSBuild cannot build an SSIS project out of the box.  You'll need a custom DLL to tell MSBuild what to do.  This is a good description of what needs to be done, but some of the links may be dated:
https://speaksql.wordpress.com/2013/06/07/a-journey-to-db-deployment-automaton-ssis-build-using-msbuild/

I put up a newer version of the msbuild project which will also help with deployment and building environments: https://github.com/MarkWojciechowicz/MSBI_Builder

This really needs a new blog post
m

Comment: Yup.  I've been trying to debug the build process on one of those MSBuild extensions, which is actually what led to the error message.  I'm trying to figure out how I can make the debugging (of this build process that is designed to extend MSBuild) less painful.  Thanks for the links, though :)

Comment: I'll put a blog post up on it, but it will be a week or so.  The process is not too painful.  What version of SSIS are you on?